# Python jQuery api GET request using datatype script return undefined response

Tags: jquery, python-3.x

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to access python network service using jQuery and getting response undefined in success event function:

api request url:

```
var hit = 'http://<domain>/api20/account2_public/signupface?FirstName=Jeevan2&LastName=Verma2&ScreenName=mssBoi2&Email=mss.abcd@gmail.com&Password=123';
```

Ajax cross domain call with 'dataType':'script':

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: hit,
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    headers: myheaders,
    success: function (data){

        alert(data); // here my response is undefined I need help here

    },
    error: function (header, status, error) {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log('ajax answer post returned error ' + header + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        alert(toSource(data));
    } 
});
```

My Browser Console Error which is my required response:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement


{"Item": {"error": "Account with that e-mail already exists"}, "Sta
```

Not Understanding is !!! if my request is success why my response data is undefined, I tried same script using jsonp and in that got parrseerror, jQuery callback not called, I tried stackoverflow answers where it has been discussed and asking this question after spending hours, kindly help me becuase I got my success event running and required response in console but wired response data alert as 'undefined'.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have JSON in response but your `dataType` is set to `script`. As said in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain
>   text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.
>   Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

You should change `dataType` to `json`:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON
>   is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON
>   formatting.)

and you'll get your response as object inside `success`.

Also note that your service returns data with `text/plain` format. If you change it to `application/json` jQuery will "guess" `dataType` itself and you may omit it in `$.ajax()` call (I myself prefer to specify `dataType`).

Comment: Thanks Twil, I end up here:"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://ec2-23-20-171-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8090/api20/account2_public/signupface?FirstName=Jeevan2&LastName=Verma2&ScreenName=mssBoi2&Email=mss.jeevanverma3@gmail.com&Password=Admin123"

Comment: @user3045332, well, now you are making cross domain request (most likely). There are different technics to overcome it. See [wiki page about CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and, for example, [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). There are a lot of questions about CORS on SO.

Comment: Thanks twil, I enabled CORS `response["headers"]["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"` everything is working now I land in success event and getting the required response, :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. You might find this interesting http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/ and read the comments about OPTIONS and POST requests.